# make two simple lines of code from python to r

Tags: python, r, pandas, machine-learning

i'm new to R and i have difficulties translating two lines of python code into r code.
the two lines are:

```
no = full_data[full_data.RainTomorrow == 0]
yes = full_data[full_data.RainTomorrow == 1]
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With `R`, we can use `$` instead of `.` and specify the `,` to signify the row index

```
no <- full_data[full_data$RainTomorrow == 0,]
yes <- full_data[full_data$RainTomorrow == 1,]
```

The assignment can be also `=`, but it is a syntax preference

---

Other options are `subset` where we don't have to specify the `objectname$` in `subset` logical expression

```
no <- subset(full_data, RainTomorrow == 0)
yes <- subset(full_data, RainTomorrow == 1)
```

---

If there are many values to subset, an easier option is `split`, which will be split the dataset into chunks of data.frame in a `list`

```
lst1 <- split(full_data, full_data$RainTomorrow)
```

and then we access each `list` element with `Extract`or symbols (`$` or `[[`

```
lst1[[1]] # // returns the first list element
lst1[["0"]] # // extract by name of the list element 
lst1$"0" # // same as above
```

Or if we want to do some transformations in each of the `list` elements, use `lapply/sapply/vapply` etc to loop over the `list`

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) <do some changes>)
```